# Return statement on Python does not seem to work (on Spyder)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have been using Python for a while and have had no problems with the IDE I've used (I've used WingIDE, now I use Spyder).

But when I started testing some code, which I typed on the editor, today, the return statement does not seem to work. Then I wrote even more basic tests which see what return does, and found out that other functions do not work properly as well.

For example for the function,

```
def test():
    return 2

'''the code below is written in the editor'''
test()
print(type(test()))
print(test())
```

After running the code on the editor.

`test()` returns 'nothing' (but it's not actually 'nothing/None/blank space')

`type(test())` returns 'nothing' (but it's not actually 'nothing/None/blank space')

`print(type(test())` prints 'class 'int' '

`print(test())` prints 2

But when I type `test()` on the console, it returns `2`, and when I type `type(test())` on the console, it returns `class: int`.

Note that the same results occur before and after I updated Spyder. And previously, the code in the editor functions the same way as the code in the console, as in typing `test()` in the editor would have returned 2 when I run the code in the editor.

Python/Spyder hasn't done anything this strange before, what happened?

Here's a visualization. Code in editor

[image]

Result after running code in editor displayed in the console

[image]

Comment: So what's the issue? type of 2 is class int.

Comment: type(2) is class int, running it on the editor returns a blank space

Comment: `print(type(test())` is unbalanced, missing a closing `)`. In that case, pressing Enter might be starting a new line in the editor since it is expecting more input?

Comment: Sorry, in the *console. Too late to edit my comment.

Comment: sorry for the typos in the original post,

check out the pictures I posted.

Comment: You didn't print the results of lines 116-118.

Comment: There weren't any results for lines 116-118, so it looks like

    runfile(the file with the editor code above)
    (new line)
    <class 'int'> is printed
    (new line)
    2 is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the missing output of lines 116-118 is what upsets you:

The editor is handling your code as a normal python script which means statements ala `test()` don't print their result.

That you get the result of something displayed immediately is a special function of the python console and not normal python behavior.

To actually print the result you have to call `print(test())` as you did in line 119-120

---

Update: After some testing in PyCharm
I got the following behavioir:

Copy&Pasting into the python console:

```
def test():
    return 2
test()
>>press enter
```

indeed results in a blank output, but this:

```
def test():
    return 2
>>press enter
test()
>>press enter
```

prints `2` as expected. So my conclusion is that Spyder is maybe not displaying the return value because it was executing a multi-instruction script instead of a single operation.

Comment: I was hoping that typing test() in the editor would RETURN 2, but it doesn't show anything on the console after I run it.

I don't want to say it returned None, because test() is of type int, but console doesn't display anything for lines 116-118.

Comment: I just did some testing and was able to reproduce this behavior, see above.

Answer (score 1):

To expand [Fabian's N.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422125/fabian-n) answer, Spyder has different evaluation models:

1. `Run file`, which is equivalent to `python my_file.py`.
2. `Run line` and `Run cell`, which copy the contents of a line or a cell to the IPython console and run it there. This model doesn't require adding `print`'s to your code.